# VS Code Python Debugging an Imported Module

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've recently git cloned a repo that I'm trying to walk through, step by step.

Say we have two files:

*main.py*

```
from utils import MyClass

print('breakpoint 1')
c = MyClass()
```

*utils.py*

```
class MyClass():
  def __init__():
    self.break_here = 'break here'
    print('break 2')
```

The above is a very simplified version, just to illustrate the issue.

In VS Code, I open the folder containing both files, so both are in the "workspace". I place a breakpoint in both *main.py* by the `print` statement, and another in *utils.py*, also by the print within the constructor.

I begin the debug process on *main.py*, and the debugger correctly stops at the print statement. However, when I try to jump into the line `c = MyClass()`, hoping the debugger will stop on the breakpoint within `utils.py`, the debugger just carries on to the end.

How do I configure/call the debugger so that it stops at the inner breakpoint within *utils.py*?

*note*: I've seen solutions about setting `justMyCode` in the launch.json file to False, however this gets really granular and I'm going through memory allocations and very granular pointer operations. I wonder if the fact that I git cloned, and I'm not the author, whether that is why it is treating the inner module `utils.py` as not my code?

Comment: My guess would be is that because when Python imports a file it complies it, the breakpoint from the VSCode tab is ignored as it's not part of the code.  So when the code is running, it doesn't see the breakpoint as it's not in the compiled code.

Comment: You could also experiment with Python's built in debugger: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: @Elan-R thank you for the comments. PDB works - it's a good suggestion. Though I would like to be able to use VS Code's debugger features.

Comment: I made a mistake in my first comment, I meant compiled, not complies.